# Paraview - Dataset locations of builtin demos / Sources

Tags: dataset, visualization, data-visualization, vtk, paraview

Paraview gets packaged with some examples. One can see them in Sources menu. Examples such as box, 2d glyph, sphere, Outline.

I'm trying to figure out how to represent these data sets, which should be .vtk files (or .html files). Does anyone know where the .vtk files for each of them are? If that's not available, is there an option, where i can extract these points, or convert my visualization into a .vtk (or .html) file? I've been trying to find out, with no success so far. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I just have to choose File -> Save Data -> Save as vtk file. How did i not see this before.

Comment: FYI, the objects in the Sources menu do not come from files. They are generated on the fly. Many of them allow you to modify their properties (for example the Resolution of a Cylinder). If you want to see what the data look like in a vtk file, your solution is correct. You may also be interested to know that starting with version 5.1, ParaView comes packaged with some example data set files. To see them, choose File -> Open and then click on the "Examples" directory in the upper left of the file dialog box.